# How to response MENU_SELECTED event in an Inherited wxMenuBar?

Tags: wxwidgets

I had tried DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE() && Connect(),but it dosen't work.My code just like this.How to make it work?

```
    //.h
        class MainFrameMenuBar :public wxMenuBar
//...
        private:
            DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
        };
/...
    //.cpp
        BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MainFrameMenuBar, wxMenuBar)
            EVT_MENU(XRCID("ID_MENU_FIGURE"), MainFrameMenuBar::onMenuItemFigure)
        END_EVENT_TABLE()

        MainFrameMenuBar::MainFrameMenuBar(wxWindow* parent)
        {
            wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadMenuBar(parent,wxT("ID_MAIN_MENUBAR"));
            //int id = XRCID("ID_MENU_FIGURE");
            //Connect(id, wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrameMenuBar::onMenuItemFigure), NULL, this);
        }

        void MainFrameMenuBar::onMenuItemFigure(wxCommandEvent& event)
        {
            printf("abc");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This used to be broken in older wxWidgets versions and you had to handle menu events only in the `wxFrame` containing the menu bar and not the menu bar itself, but it should have been [fixed](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15095) quite some time ago, so perhaps you need to upgrade?

If you do use a version affected by that bug and can't upgrade, handling the events in the frame is the simplest workaround.

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.0. Is there something other wrong?

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong in the code shown here, so I don't know what could be wrong. As always, if you could try to reproduce the problem in an existing wxWidgets sample such as the [minimal sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/v3.1.0/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp), it could narrow down the problem, e.g. we would at least know if it's related to using XRC or independent of it etc.